# Live Updating Component Callback Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am having trouble wrapping my head around Dash component callbacks. I am simply trying to update on an interval. The backend that I am pointing to is a database that will update. Below is what I am working with. The function produces the figure I want well, but when the datasource inevitably updates I would like the figure to reflect that.

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(
children=[
    html.Div(id="Graphs", children=[dcc.Graph(id='lapTime')]),
    dcc.Interval(id='interval-component', 
                 interval=1 * 1000, 
                 n_intervals=0)
    
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output('Graphs', 'children'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def lapTimePlot():
      # SQL Calls for data
    channel = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};~~connection String Omitted~~") 
    Run=pd.read_sql("SQL OMITTED", channel).iloc[0]['Name']
    Event=pd.read_sql("SQL OMITTED", channel).iloc[0]['evID']
    Lap=pd.read_sql("SQL OMITTED", channel)
    #Clean Data
    Lap=Lap[Lap['RunName']==Run]
    Lap=Lap[Lap['evID']==Event]
    Lap=Lap[Lap['Ltime']>10] 
    Lap=Lap[Lap['Ltime']<(Lap['Ltime'].min()*1.1)]
    # Generate tables and sort values
    med=Lap.groupby(['Driver'])['Ltime'].median().sort_values()
    mini=Lap.groupby(['Driver'])['Ltime'].min().sort_values()
    # Combine tables and put into dataframe
    tab=pd.concat([mini,med],axis=1)
    tab=tab.reset_index()
    tab.columns = ['Driver','Min_Ltime','Mean_Ltime']
    tab=tab.sort_values('Min_Ltime',ascending=True) 
    tab=tab.reset_index(drop=True)
    tab=tab.reset_index()
    tab.columns = ['Rank','Driver','Min_Ltime','Mean_Ltime']
    tab.Rank=tab.Rank+1
    tab=tab.round({'Min_Ltime': 3,'Mean_Ltime': 3})
    # Set order by laptime
    Lap['Driver_Sort']= pd.Categorical(Lap['Driver'], categories=tab.Driver, ordered=True)
    Lap=Lap.sort_values('Driver_Sort',ascending=True)   
    ses="Session: " + Run  
    rheight=650/tab.Driver.count()   
    #Generate Table
    trace=go.Table(
                domain=dict(x=[0,0.2],
                            y=[0,1]),
                columnwidth=[1, 3, 1, 1],
                header=dict(
                values=["Rank","Driver", "Fast Lap", "Mean Lap",],
                height=50,
                font=dict(size=10),
                align="center"),
                cells=dict(
                values=tab.transpose().values.tolist(),
                height=rheight)) 
    
      # Generate box plot
    trace1=go.Box(
              x=Lap['Ltime'], y=Lap['Driver'] ,
              notched=True,
              orientation='h',
              xaxis="x1",
              yaxis="y1")
    layout = dict(xaxis1=dict( dict(domain=[0.28, 1], anchor='y1')),
                 yaxis1=dict( dict(domain=[0.05, 0.93], anchor='x1')),
                 title_text=ses) 
    Fig1 = go.Figure(data = [trace,trace1], layout = layout)
    return Fig1



if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run_server(debug=False)
```

I am struggling to see where this is going pear shaped. First time working with Dash and callbacks.

The page opens, and is updating every 1 second like it is supposed to, but the graph has nothing on it and is seemingly not being rendered by the `lapTimePlot()`

UPDATE:

When running with `app.run_server(debug=True,use_reloader=False)` there are no errors that can be seen when debugging.

Comment: What is the value of `Fig1`? We can't diagnose the problem without knowing what the value of `Fig1` is. I would also include the "data gathering and producing the figure from the database" part in the question. Also for testing set `debug` to `True`. There's a good chance it will tell you what the problem is that way.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden I have updated the question with the figure creation as well as the issue when running `app.run_server(debug=True)`

Comment: What happens if you change the interval to something longer, like 20 seconds? If the callback takes so long to execute that it fires again, it will never update on the page. With a database call happening, it could just need more time.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I can identify is that you're missing a parameter for your callback function.

Each callback function requires at least one `Input` and `Output`. The inputs map to the parameters of the callback function by their position.

```
@app.callback(Output("Graphs", "children"), Input("interval-component", "n_intervals"))
def lapTimePlot(n_intervals):
    # Do something...
```

You need to supply this parameter here even if you don't use it in the callback. You can name it something else as long as you supply a number of parameters to `lapTimePlot` equal to the number of `Input`s used.